# share sample of website designed in localhost with clients

Tags: localhost, sharing

I am a beginner in WordPress web design. When I want to apply for a job they ask me to send some experience profile or portfolios.
I can create different type of website on localhost, however I want to share some of my sample work online such that to be presented to clients or recruiters.

My question is: Is there any website that I can upload my portfolios/sample of websites which I created in localhost, and the recruiter or clients can view and browse them.

P.S. I remember once I watched a tutorial video, something like this was discussed but I do not remember that video name :(

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using [local by flywheel](https://localwp.com/)? its a local wordpress development environment that has the option for what you are asking. specifically [live links](https://localwp.com/live-links/).

Comment: @Buttered_Toast, thanks, but how can I do that?

Comment: You would need to read the doumentation about that, the links I provided should give you a good starting point